# while twig {% render %} no error page symfony2

Tags: symfony, render, twig

If I run the controller "normally" the (Booking) Controller throws an exception I get my custom 500 error page.

If I render the controller inside another template, like so:

```
{% render "BookingBundle:Booking:list" %}
```

then I don't get anything just blank output.

Is there a way to get the error page to display here with out doing a try catch inside the controller?

Comment: I don't think so. However, why should you get a 500 error in your controller?

Comment: uncaught exception or syntax error. Sorry just though the controller is not throwing the exception its a service that the controller is using that throws the exception.

Comment: Well, a working application shouldn't throw exceptions that are not caught or generate syntax errors, so I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. If you see the controller's response is blank, have a look at the logs, find the problem and fix it. But you won't need it in a production environment.

Comment: The other thing I just noticed is that the error log does not log the thrown exception if you render the controller inside the template. but it does get logged if you run the controller from the url ???

Comment: Are you in **dev** environment?

Comment: no prod the prod.log only contains the fatal if I run though the a url.

Comment: You have to use the **dev** environment. The error coming from the bundled controller should be logged then.

Comment: yeh it will be. I just found why it does not log to the error log when you render it via the a twig file. In HttpKernel->render() there is this line "if (!$options['ignore_errors']) {throw $e;}" so if it is a "render" exception it gets hidden from the log files, which in this case it is a render exception as it bubbles up from the template.

Comment: My main concern was I don't really want production to hide errors they should be going to the error log but in this case they do not.

Comment: I guess this is the bug that should be reported on GitHub.

Comment: I know this issue is old but it's still a problem I ran into recently. I've created a GItHub issue about it: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6400

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use the render tag, you can specify some options as the third argument:

- **ignore_errors** default FALSE in debug mode and TRUE otherwise
- **alt** an alternative controller to execute in case of an error

The debug mode is activated by passing `true` as the value of the second kernel's constructor argument. You can see it in the front controller classes:

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
```

If you don't want to ignore errors, even in non-debug mode, you can do:

```
{% render 'BookingBundle:Booking:list' with {}, {'ignore_errors':false} %}
```

Comment: brilliant thanks the "alt" sounds like what I want. I hate blank screens with no explanation. If I can run an alternative controller and just display a message that says "an error occurred" that would be brilliant and at the same time perhaps log something went wrong. Silently dying to the user is not my idea of fun, it can cause confusion (Not that my code will ever have bugs that will trigger this alt controller :) ). Thanks again